# Populating a dropdownlistbox in VB.net 2010 winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, drop-down-menu

I am new to winforms and I am trying to populate a dropdownlistbox with data returned from the database. I have a ClaimID & ClaimType.

I can't seem to get the syntax correct. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is your syntax then? "Data returned from the database" is not exactly helpful, or specific.

Comment: Please post the syntax you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

if your data is in datatable named dt, then

```
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ClaimId"
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ClaimType"
ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
```